# Let $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda=2$ find $\mathbb{E}[N_3N_4].$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

> Let $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda=2.$
>   Find $\mathbb{E}[N_3N_4].$

The solution here is

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[N_3N_4]&=\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3+N_3)]\tag1\\ 
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3)+N_3^2]\tag2\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3)]+\mathbb{E}[N_3^2]\tag3\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_4-N_3)]+\mathbb{Var}[N_3]+\mathbb{E}[N_3]^2\tag4\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3N_1]+\mathbb{Var}[N_3]+\mathbb{E}[N_3]^2\tag5\\
&=\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_1]+\mathbb{Var}[N_3]+\mathbb{E}[N_3]^2\tag6\\
&=6\cdot2+6+6^2=54\tag7
\end{align}

My question is: Why is $N_3$ and $N_1$ independent but not $N_3$ and $N_4$? I assume independence is the reason we can go in (5) from $\mathbb{E}[N_3N_1]$ to (6) where we instead get $\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_1]$?

**EDIT/addition:**

In the next question in my book, they ask me to explain why the following *proof* is wrong:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(N_3)^2]=\mathbb{E}[N_3N_3]=\mathbb{E}[N_3(N_6-N_3)]=\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_6-N_3]=\mathbb{E}[N_3]\mathbb{E}[N_3]=\mathbb{E}[N_3]^2.
\end{align}

Their answer is that $N_3\neq N_6-N_3$. I find this contradicting because in the previous assignment above, I get to use that $N_4-N_3=N_1$.

Comment: $N_3$ and $N_1$ are not independent, $N_3$ and $N_4-N_3$ is independent due to independent increment and $N_4-N_3$ is equally distributed with $N_1$. There is a minor mistake in the step. It should be $E(N_3(N_4-N_3))=E(N_3)E((N_4-N_3))=E(N_3)E(N_1).$

Comment: @John_Wick - This is really confusing, If $N_3$ and $N_4-N_3$ are independent and if $N_4-N_3=N_1$, then $N_3$ and $N_1$ are independent. Same as if $a$ and $b$ are independent and if $b=c+d$ then $a$ and $c+d$ are also independent. What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" That $N_4-N_3\ne N_1$, not at all, not in the least, absolutely not. But $N_4-N_3\stackrel d= N_1$, yes, by definition.

Comment: @Did But according to John_Wick's last equations one is led to draw the incorrect conclusion that $N_4-N_3=N_1.$ Guess It's just a matter of notational abuse by my prof, as Michael Lugo points out.

Comment: @Parseval No, John_Wick does not say that $N_4-N_3=N_1$, only that $E(N_4-N_3)=E(N_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$N_3$ and $N_1$ are not independent.  (They can't be!  Clearly the time until the third point in your Poisson process depends on the time until the first one - for example, trivially $N_3 > N_1$.)  But $N_4 - N_3$ doesn't equal $N_1$, either.  This is an abuse of notation.

The $N_1$ in line 5 really should be written as something like $\tilde{N}_1$ - it's the first arrival time of the Poisson process starting at time $N_3$.  Then you have $E(N_3 (N_4 - N_3)) = E(N_3 \tilde{N}_1) = E(N_3) E(\tilde{N}_1)$.  But since $(\tilde{N}_t)_{t \ge 0}$ is again a Poisson process with $\lambda = 2$ you have $E(\tilde{N}_1) = E(N_1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I see now that the notation confused me. I added something in my question right as you answered, could you please explain if I'm now correct in saying that $$E(N_3)E(N_6-N_3)=E(N_3)E(\tilde{N_3})=E(N_3)E(\tilde{N_3})\neq E(N_3)^2?$$

Comment: ?? Why the last $\ne$ sign? Of course $E(N_6-N_3)=E(N_3)$.